# Asana API Cross-Domain Request Access Control Headers

Tags: asana

I'm trying to make a GET request to the Asana API from the browser.  Because this is a cross-domain request, the client first sends an OPTIONS request.  I'm running into the same issue that was described in this Stack Overflow question a year ago, [ASANA API and Access-Control-* headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567884/asana-api-and-access-control-headers), where the Asana API doesn't respond with the Access-Control parameters.

I'm wondering whether the new release of the Asana Connect and OAuth2 addresses this problem and I'm simply doing something wrong or if this is still unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana.) Sorry, looks like this slipped through the cracks.

We currently do not allow Cross-Origin requests. However, we do support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if you use  Oauth2 and authenticate with a bearer token. This allows you to make secure requests from a JS client.

Just append `opt_jsonp=CALLBACK` as a parameter to the request, where `CALLBACK` is the name of the javascript function you would like to be called back with the response data.

Comment: Has JSONP support been implemented for all API calls? I'm able to get an authorization token via OAuth2. However, when I make API calls with "?jsonp=..." I just get a JSON object back rather than the expected JavaScript code.

Comment: Terribly sorry, the answer should have read you use ?opt_jsonp= instead of ?jsonp= as all of our options are prefixed with opt_. I've edited the answer, and apologize for any frustration that may have caused you.